# use f:convertNumber inside h:link

Tags: jsf-2, hyperlink, formatting

I want to format a link like currency. Does anyone know a good way of dealing with such an issue? I'm using Mojarra, JSF 2, PrimeFaces. Usage of a `<f:facet>` would be ideal, like in following example:

```
<h:link outcome="/somePage.xhtml">
    <f:facet name="value">
        <h:outputText value="#{result.price}">
            <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" locale="de" />
        </h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <f:param name="id" value="#{result.id}" />
    <f:param name="windowId" value="" />
    <f:param name="parentWindowId" value="#{windowId}" />
</h:link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look much like that you're overcomplicating things. The `<f:facet name="value">` is completely unnecessary. The `<h:link>` component's support for it is also not listed anywhere in the [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html).

This works as expected:

```
<h:link outcome="/somePage.xhtml">
    <h:outputText value="#{result.price}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" locale="de" />
    </h:outputText>
    <f:param name="id" value="#{result.id}" />
    <f:param name="windowId" value="" />
    <f:param name="parentWindowId" value="#{windowId}" />
</h:link>
```